# Using Salesforce Named Credentials Against Google IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, salesforce, google-iap

### Goal

I have built a REST API that is running on Google App Engine, protected by [Google Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) (Identity Aware Proxy). My goal is to use a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) to make requests to this API from Salesforce (using the [External Services](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_services.htm&type=5) feature).

### Context

Thanks to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975694/authenticating-against-an-iap-protected-resource-with-bearer-header), I understand that I will need to use [JWT Token Exchange](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-09.html) for this flow to request an [OIDC](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) token. So the next step is understanding how to fill out Salesforce's [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) definition:

[image: Salesforce Named Credentials JWT Token Exchange]

The properties of a [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) are as follows:

1. **Certificate:** Not applicable to my use case.
2. **Identity Type:** Whether to use different credentials for each accessing Salesforce user or a single credential across the board. I will be using *Named Principal*.
3. **Authentication Protocol:** I [now realize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975694/authenticating-against-an-iap-protected-resource-with-bearer-header) that JWT Token Exchange is required.
4. **Token Endpoint Url:** The JSON downloaded for the Service Account specifies `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`.
5. **Scope:** I am unsure of the correct value for this property, maybe it should be `openid email`?
6. **Issuer:** No idea what this should be.
7. **Named Principal Subject:** I think this should be the *client_email* value from the Service Account. However, this documentation says "Request an OIDC token for the IAP-secured client ID." Does that mean I should use the client ID from the IAP *Client ID for Web application* page instead?
8. **Audiences:** The only value I can find that may be appropriate is from the IAP Signed Header JWT found in the HTTPS Resources section of the GCP Console in the form `/projects/NNNNN/apps/XXXXXXX`.
9. **Token Valid for:** I believe this should be 1 hour.
10. **JWT Signing Certificate:** The [Service Account private key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).
11. **Generate Authorization Header:** Should be enabled.

### Questions:

1. Can anyone confirm my understanding as well as assist with the Scope, Issuer, and Named Principal Subject fields?
2. The [IAP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) talks about an JWT *additional claim* `target_audience` being required, where does that end up?

Comment: I wrote an article on how to create the access token including the JWT fields. I don't know anything about Salescorce. Once you have a signed JWT, you exchange that for an Access Token and OIDC Token. I don't see anything in the Salesforce form to do that. Just signing a JWT is not enough. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I'll read your article and code up a client so I can at least understand the flow outside of Salesforce. The options available include OAuth 2.0, JWT, and JWT Token Exchange.

Comment: If you are stuck, I might volunteer to help you. I know this area of GCP very well. Might make for an interesting article for my website. Contact me thru my site.

Comment: @AdamSherman Have you ever found a solution for using Named Credentials with IAP, especially supporting that target_audience attribute?

Comment: @AdamSherman can you share how you uploaded the JWT Signing Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I think `target_audience` cloud be the iapClientId located on your IAP dashboard. Just like what mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto).

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.app_engine
import google.auth.compute_engine.credentials
import google.auth.iam
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.oauth2.service_account
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine


IAM_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'
OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'


def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs):
    """Makes a request to an application protected by Identity-Aware Proxy.

    Args:
      url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
      client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.
      method: The request method to use
              ('GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')
      **kwargs: Any of the parameters defined for the request function:
                https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py
                If no timeout is provided, it is set to 90 by default.

    Returns:
      The page body, or raises an exception if the page couldn't be retrieved.
    """
    # Set the default timeout, if missing
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = 90

    # Figure out what environment we're running in and get some preliminary
    # information about the service account.
    bootstrap_credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[IAM_SCOPE])
    if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                  google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials):
        raise Exception('make_iap_request is only supported for service '
                        'accounts.')
    elif isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                    google.auth.app_engine.Credentials):
        requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

    # For service account's using the Compute Engine metadata service,
    # service_account_email isn't available until refresh is called.
    bootstrap_credentials.refresh(Request())

    signer_email = bootstrap_credentials.service_account_email
    if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                  google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials):
        # Since the Compute Engine metadata service doesn't expose the service
        # account key, we use the IAM signBlob API to sign instead.
        # In order for this to work:
        #
        # 1. Your VM needs the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam scope.
        #    You can specify this specific scope when creating a VM
        #    through the API or gcloud. When using Cloud Console,
        #    you'll need to specify the "full access to all Cloud APIs"
        #    scope. A VM's scopes can only be specified at creation time.
        #
        # 2. The VM's default service account needs the "Service Account Actor"
        #    role. This can be found under the "Project" category in Cloud
        #    Console, or roles/iam.serviceAccountActor in gcloud.
        signer = google.auth.iam.Signer(
            Request(), bootstrap_credentials, signer_email)
    else:
        # A Signer object can sign a JWT using the service account's key.
        signer = bootstrap_credentials.signer

    # Construct OAuth 2.0 service account credentials using the signer
    # and email acquired from the bootstrap credentials.
    service_account_credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
        signer, signer_email, token_uri=OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, additional_claims={
            'target_audience': client_id
        })

    # service_account_credentials gives us a JWT signed by the service
    # account. Next, we use that to obtain an OpenID Connect token,
    # which is a JWT signed by Google.
    google_open_id_connect_token = get_google_open_id_connect_token(
        service_account_credentials)

    # Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an
    # Authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
    # Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
    resp = requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
    if resp.status_code == 403:
        raise Exception('Service account {} does not have permission to '
                        'access the IAP-protected application.'.format(
                            signer_email))
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
                resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
    else:
        return resp.text


def get_google_open_id_connect_token(service_account_credentials):
    """Get an OpenID Connect token issued by Google for the service account.

    This function:

      1. Generates a JWT signed with the service account's private key
         containing a special "target_audience" claim.

      2. Sends it to the OAUTH_TOKEN_URI endpoint. Because the JWT in #1
         has a target_audience claim, that endpoint will respond with
         an OpenID Connect token for the service account -- in other words,
         a JWT signed by *Google*. The aud claim in this JWT will be
         set to the value from the target_audience claim in #1.

    For more information, see
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount .
    The HTTP/REST example on that page describes the JWT structure and
    demonstrates how to call the token endpoint. (The example on that page
    shows how to get an OAuth2 access token; this code is using a
    modified version of it to get an OpenID Connect token.)
    """

    service_account_jwt = (
        service_account_credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion())
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    body = {
        'assertion': service_account_jwt,
        'grant_type': google.oauth2._client._JWT_GRANT_TYPE,
    }
    token_response = google.oauth2._client._token_endpoint_request(
        request, OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, body)
    return token_response['id_token']
```

Comment: Turns out Salesforce doesn’t support the specific token exchange required by Google.

Comment: @AdamSherman Is that in the docs somewhere? Wondering how you found out it wasn't supported?

Comment: It's a while ago @RyanDawson, but I could not make it work and could not find a single example. In fact, all the examples from Salesforce and Google do it manually in Apex. Have you tried it?